# pass one variables value to another variable in flutter

Tags: flutter

In my flutter app I created variables `var from, to;` and pass those with their values to the next page. which I used it with the `widget.from` & `widget.to`.
but how can i pass this `widget.from` & `widget.to` variables to `var newFrom, newTo;` these variables?

Comment: Where is `newFrom` and `newTo`?

Comment: they are in the second screen

Answer (score 0):

```
class FirstPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var from = "Five", to = "Ten";
    return SecondPage(from: from, to: to);
  }
}



class SecondPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final from, to;
  const SecondPage({Key key, this.from, this.to}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _SecondPageState createState() => _SecondPageState();
}

class _SecondPageState extends State<SecondPage> {
  var newFrom = "", newTo = "";

  @override
  void initState() {
    setState(() {
      newFrom = widget.from;
      newTo = widget.to;
    });
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Text("$newFrom $newTo"),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: actually I was passing this in `stream.builder`  using firestore `where` query. when i use it in a simple text widget it works but not in firestore `where` query